# how call to mobile no using twilio.com with php coding

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, computer-science

this is html code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Automated call form</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Automated Call Form</h1>
  <p>Fill in all fields and click <b>Make this call</b>.</p>
  <form action="twilio.php" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>To:</td>
        <td><input name="callTo" size="50" type="text" value=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>From:</td>
        <td><input name="callFrom" size="50" type="text" value=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Call message:</td>
        <td><input name="callText" size="100" type="text" value="Hello. This is the call text. Good bye."></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Make this call"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form><br>
</body>
</html>
```

this is php coding

```
     <html>
<head><title>Making a call</title></head>
<body>
<p>Your call is being made.</p>

<?php
//require_once 'path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
$sid   = "ACd544115bc5442c8633f2483e09318048";
$token = "6514bba4074a8c7b3df634aff9045874";
$from_number = $_POST['callFrom']; // Calls must be made from a registered Twilio number.
$to_number   = $_POST['callTo'];
$message     = $_POST['callText'];
$client = new Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);
$call = $client->calls->create(
        $to_number,
        $from_number,
      array(
      'url' => 'https://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.ambient')
);
echo "Call status: " . $call->status . "<br />";
echo "URI resource: " . $call->uri . "<br />";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

i am register on twilio.com which provide comunication facilities but i am confused how am i using in correct way
in html file just form input number from and to using call but when i click make a call button no call transfer or recieve in my no.